# Permission denied for a file that was generated by PHP

Tags: php, apache, permissions, fopen, unlink

I am running Apache on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Instead of using `$_SESSION`, I use temporary files to save data that is used/called very often "to reduce the session file locks." Inside a folder `C:\phpsites\add-ons\icws\cache`, I create the temp files using PHP function `fopen()`

Additionally, I have a job that delete old temp filed using PHP `unlick()` function. Old file is a file that is not used for a while which is evaluated randomly at 5% rate.

However, I keep seeing a PHP Warning in the PHP logs regarding permission denied! Below is a line from the log file

```
[14-Aug-2015 09:24:55 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  unlink(C:\phpsites\add-ons\icws\ICWS/../cache/201508142554086002): Permission denied in C:\phpsites\add-ons\icws\ICWS\CacheHandler.php on line 172
```

Why would the permission be denied if the file was generated by the script?

Yes, the file could be generated by request A using `fopen()` and the delete request could be coming from request B `unlink()`.

Comment: it's windows. you can grant permission to create files, but not delete them... check the permissions of the containing folder(s).

Comment: Also check the file permissions itself. I mean if that is said to be an issue, then you should not try to _guess_ that they should be deletable. Look at the specific permissions.

Comment: What Group or user name will I need to check?

Comment: Do a chmod 777 on folder and create a file

Comment: @IlanHasanov chmod is a lunix command not windows